# Directing on a specific tab by a button on another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have no idea what am I exactly to do on how can I redirect on a specific tab by a button from another page.

Example:

I'm on HOME Page and I have button "Go to New Clients".

When I click that button, it will go to another page called "Client Page".

**Client Page has 3 tabs:**

- All Client (which is active)
- New Client
- Old Client

What I want to do is, when I click the button "Go to New Clients" from Home page, It will redirect to Client Page and directly/automatically open the "New Client" tab as active.

I'm using bootstrap and jquery.

**UPDATE**

---

here's my Client page:

```
- provide(:title, 'Client Database')
.row.page-header.page-header-with-buttons
  %h1.pull-left
    %i.icon-group
    %span Clients
  = render 'shared/main_navigation'
.row
  .col-xs-12
    = render 'shared/profile_menu'
  .col-sm-12.box{style: "margin-bottom: 0"}
    .box
      .box-header.gray-background
        .heading-title 
          %strong CLIENT DATABASE
      .box-content
        #client_tabs.tabbable{style: "margin-top: 20px"}
          %ul.nav.nav-responsive.nav-tabs
            %li.active
              = link_to 'All', '#all_clients', :'data-toggle' => 'tab', :'data-url' => '/clients/all/list'
            %li
              = link_to 'New Client', '#new_clients', :'data-toggle' => 'tab', :'data-url' => '/clients/new_client/list'
            %li
              = link_to 'Old Client', '#old_clients', :'data-toggle' => 'tab', :'data-url' => '/clients/old_client/list'
            %li
              = link_to 'Corporate', '#corporate', :'data-toggle' => 'tab', :'data-url' => '/clients/corporate/list'
            %li
              = link_to 'Individual', '#individual', :'data-toggle' => 'tab', :'data-url' => '/clients/individual/list'
          .tab-content
            #all_clients.tab-pane.active
            #new_clients.tab-pane
            #old_clients.tab-pane
            #corporate.tab-pane
            #individual.tab-pane
```

JQUERY:

```
$('#client_tabs ul .active a').trigger('click')
```

HOME PAGE:

```
= link_to 'New Client', '#new_clients', :'data-toggle' => 'tab', :'data-url' => '/clients/new_client/list', class: 'btn btn-success'
```

Comment: please share the html first.

Comment: You need to set the tab class to active based on the page you're on. Can't really help without any code.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it via angular js. Although it's a steep learning curve to using angular it makes life much easier writing javascipt and creating dynamic web pages. There is an example for what you are looking using angular  here (under tab):
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/